# C, #if directive and compilation error: operator '/' has no right operand

Tags: c, if-statement, preprocessor

I ran into an error which I don't understand, mainly because if refers to a commented portion of the code

Basically I have something like:

```
#ifndef nH
    #define nH 2  // number of hermitian matrices
#endif
```

And then I have an #if directive

```
#if (nH != 0)
    gsl_matrix_complex* H[nH];       // hermitian operators
    gsl_vector* evalH[nH];           // eigenvalues of H
#endif
```

If I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
error: operator '/' has no right operand
     #define nH 2    // number of hermitian matrices
```

I solved the issue by simply putting the comment above the #define like this:

```
// number of hermitian matrices
#ifndef nH
    #define nH 2
#endif
```

Also, the error does not occur if I cancel the #if directive.
Still, I don't understand the issue and I'd like to know what exactly went wrong

Thanks

edit:
so, now I tried to replicate it and it compiles perfectly. I don't know, all I can do is to post a screenshot of the error I got. As you can see there is no space between the two /
[image: error]

Comment: You are using a _comment_ in a define clause: `// number of hermitian matrices` If your preprocessor handles defines before comments, that could cause the problem

Comment: What compiler are you using? I can't reproduce.

Comment: @Psi: That's not a problem.

Comment: @Olaf that depends on the preprocessor I would say

Comment: Perhaps you're using an ancient preprocessor. Does using `/**/`-style comments fix the problem?

Comment: @Psi: No, it is defined by the standard.

Comment: Theoretically, as per standard, comments are removed before the preprocessor is run. This smells like an ancient buggy implementation to me.

Comment: define is basically replacing and maybe you cant put a comment near the define statement. Because your code might try to replace every nH with "2    // number of hermitian matrices" directly. Causing the division problem.

Comment: That's what I mean. Only because it's standard doesn't mean it's implemented correctly everywhere

Comment: @DeiDei: Actually removing comments is part of the preprocessor. Just a different stage.

Comment: @Psi: That is most likely not an error, but as PSkocik wrote some non-standard compiler which supports only K&R or C90.

Comment: @Olaf ehm... correct? So why is there a need for a discussion? If that's the case, an attempt to move the comment outside of the definition is worth a try. That's where I pointed to

Comment: sorry I don't know if I'm supposed to comment or edit the post, anyway I'm using gcc 4.8.4

Comment: @MauroD'Arcangelo Are you sure? https://godbolt.org/g/3Jd3Aw 4.8.4 seems to preprocess it just fine.

Comment: now it's compiling...I don't know what to say, I spent a good hour on this...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you preprocess with the language set to at least C99.

If you preprocess:

```
#ifndef nH
    #define nH 2  // number of hermitian matrices
#endif
#if (nH != 0)
#endif
```

with

```
gcc-4.8 -std=c89 -E pp.c
```

you'll get `pp.c:2:20: error: operator '/' has no right operand`

but you shouldn't get this error message if you set the language to c99 or newer (`gnu*` variants starting with `gnu89` work too)

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that there is no space between // you used for adding comment, 
The error you are getting is possible only when there is any space in between two, In this case it would be considered as Division expression and as you have not written any number on right side of first slash(/)that's why compiler is giving you this error.

Comment: I thought about that, but there was no space...I added a screenshot of the error on the main post

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.8.4. Unfortunately (or luckily) I solved the issue by putting the comment above (not on the same line) and now I can't replicate the error even if I try